# Discrete logarithmic colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: colormap

I want to create a `pcolormesh` plot with a **discrete** logarithmic colorbar. Some resolution is lost, but the matching between colors and values seems to be easier (at least for me) if the colormap is discrete.

The code snippet below produces a continuous log colormap with the preferred value range. How can I make it discrete? [Here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html) I found how to create a discrete linear colormap, but I couldn't extend it to log scale.

```
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z,norm=mcolors.LogNorm(vmin=0.01, vmax=100.))
plt.colorbar()
fig  = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4*2.5, 3*2.5)
plt.xlabel("X", horizontalalignment='right', x=1.0)
plt.ylabel("Y", horizontalalignment='right', y=1.0)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Continuous log scale]

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to create a logarithmic colorbar with even spacing. However, I couldn't figure out how to create a discrete logarithmic colorbar with a logarithmic spacing of the colorbar. I hope this helps!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(0, 50)
Y = np.arange(0, 50)
Z = np.random.rand(50, 50)*10
bounds = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, .7, .8, .9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
num_c = len(bounds)
cmap = mpl.colormaps['viridis'].resampled(num_c)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

fig, ax  = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(4*2.5, 3*2.5)

ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
plt.xlabel("X", horizontalalignment='right', x=1.0)
plt.ylabel("Y", horizontalalignment='right', y=1.0)

fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm))
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]